# How far can I push a ball of radius r into the corner of a convex polytope in d-dimensions?

Tags: mg.metric-geometry

Let $K \subset \mathbb{R}^d$ be a convex polytope and let $B(x,r) = \{y \in \mathbb{R}^d \,:\, \Vert y-x \Vert_2 \leq r\}$ be the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$.

For any radius $r \geq 0$ let $K_r= \{x \in K \,:\, B(x,r) \subset K\}$ be the set of all points $x$ in $K$ such that a ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$ is contained entirely in $K$.

My question is: how far away is the furthest point in $K$ from $K_r$? Specifically, what is
$$
\sup_{x \in K} \inf_{y \in K_r} \Vert x - y \Vert_2?
$$
Intuitively, it depends on how pointy the corners of $K$ are. Alternatively, if the maximum distance is complicated, then is there a simple upper bound that goes to $0$ as $r \to 0$?

Comment: As soon as $K_r$ is not empty (say $r\le r_0$) the maximum point $x$ is a vertex (it maximizes a convex function), and it is the same for all $r\le r_0$. By a similarity argument, the answer has the form $Cr$ for some $C$ only depending from the vertex. Thus for a complete answer you need to treat the case where K is a cone spanned by $u_1,u_2,\dots,u_m$, and $r=1$. This should not be too difficult.